# ogr2ogr KY GIS Import

Tags: ogr

Using ogr2ogr I was able to import a shapefile into SQL server, but it was imported as a geometry data type and not compatible to compare it to latitude longitude as the points were not correct on the polygons.

`gdal\bin\gdal\apps\ogr2ogr -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial -lco SRID=4326 -lco GEOM_TYPE=geography -a_srs "GIS\Kentucky\HH001M01.prj" "MSSQL:server=.\;database=GISData;trusted_connection=yes" "GIS\Kentucky\HH001M01.shp"`

The last command I ran was above, but it gave an error that the Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees. Which makes sense, but I don't know how to apply the project correctly to get it to convert the shapefile to the right format.

Am I missing a parameter to ogr2ogr or have I specified something wrong?

Data
HH001M01 is the data I am using here.
http://www.lrc.ky.gov/gis/gis_data.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you want transform the shapefile to the server in lat/lon, use `-t_srs EPSG:4326`.

The options `-a_srs <some non-lat/lon projection>` and `-lco SRID=4326` logically conflict. I don't think you need `-a_srs` for this operation, since it would implied to be the same as `-t_srs`.

Comment: This got me going in the right direction. I had to remove -lco GEOM_Type=geography and then run the sql below. Something about the left hand rule and when it was a geography type it took over the entire globe, but geometry it worked. I still had one record that was correct, so I had to flip it by updating one record without ReorientObject()
 UPDATE [hh001m01] SET [ogr_geometry] = [ogr_geometry].MakeValid();
  ALTER TABLE [hh001m01] ADD ogr_geography geography; 
  update [hh001m01]
  SET ogr_geography = geography::STGeomFromWKB(ogr_geometry.STAsBinary(), 4326).MakeValid().ReorientObject()